# How do I call a base class method from within the same overloaded derived class method in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following classes setup in my python project,

In MicroSim.py

```
class MicroSim:
    def __init__(self, other_values):
        # init stuff here

    def _generate_file_name(self, integer_value):
        # do some stuff here

    def run(self):
        # do some more stuff
        self._generate_file_name(i)
```

In ThresholdCollabSim.py

```
from MicroSim import MicroSim

class ThresholdCollabSim (MicroSim):
    # no __init__() implmented

    def _generate_file_name(self, integer_value):
        # do stuff here
        super(ThresholdCollabSim, self)._generate_file_name(integer_value) # I'm trying to call MicroSim._generate_file_name() here

    # run() method is not re-implemented in Derived!
```

In MicroSimRunner.py

```
from ThresholdCollabSim import ThresholdCollabSim

def run_sims(values):
    thresholdSim = ThresholdCollabSim(some_values) # I assume since ThresholdCollabSim doesn't have it's own __init__() the MicroSim.__init() will be used here
    thresholdSim.run() # again, the MicroSim.run() method should be called here since ThresholdCollabSim.run() doesn't exist
```

When I run this code I get the error msg,

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "stdin", line 1, in
>      File "H:...\MicroSimRunner.py", line 11, in run_sims
>       thresholdSim.run()   File "H:...\MicroSim.py", line 42, in run
>       self._generate_file_name(r)   File "H:...\ThresholdCollabSim.py", line 17, in _generate_file_name
>       super(ThresholdCollabSim, self)._generate_file_name(curr_run) TypeError: unbound method _generate_file_name() must be
>   called with MicroSim instance as first argument (got int instance
>   instead)

I have tried searching for issues like this here and have found similar posts and have tried all the solutions discussed there but this error doesn't seem to go away. I have tried changing the line in question to,

```
super(ThresholdCollabSim, self)._generate_file_name(self, curr_run)
```

but it changes nothing (same error). I am relatively new at Python programming so this may just be a silly mistake. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to make MicroSim a new-style class by using `class MicroSim(object)`.

Comment: What about `ThresholdCollabSim._generate_file_name(self, curr_run)`?

Comment: `ThresholdCollabSim._generate_file_name(self, curr_run)` doesn't help. What is a new-style class?

Comment: Making MicroSim a new-style class worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `self` argument in your derived `_generate_file_name` method.  Also, you need to make MicroSim a new-style class by using `class MicroSim(object)`.

Comment: Missing "self" typo on my part when I was writing out the question, it's been fixed. It does not solve the problem though. What is a new-style class?

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement.

You use `super` in the old-style class.

From the [`super`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) documentation, we know that:

> super() only works for new-style classes.

And a new-style class is

> Any class which inherits from object.